# How to setup power button to sleep instead of shut down in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, shutdown, hibernate

I pressed the power button 0.1 seconds and I was surprised that the system shut down. 
I just wanted to hibernate it or to make it sleep such that all windows will be the same when I next time login. 
I would like to understand how the system has been designed to work like that, since I want to work mostly with defaults.

Why does Windows then shut down when pressing shortly power button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change what the power button does, follow these steps:

1. Go to settings
2. Go to System > Power & Sleep
3. Click additional power settings
4. Click choose what the power button does
5. Change the settings to suit your needs

Comment: so default of pressing power button shortly means shut down. Right?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure the time has nothing to do with the action.

Comment: @RookieTEC9 On many laptops/PCs holding the power button down for a long time (instead of a short press) will do a forced shutdown (useful when the machine is hung). That is independent of any power settings.

Comment: Sorry about that comment. FYI, he never asks about holding down the power button long-ishly.